# solving quadratic congruence but overflows in mathematica

Tags: elementary-number-theory, mathematica

I am solving $x^2 \equiv a\pmod{p}$, here $a = 73$ and $p = 370370384407407431.$

My Mathematica code is

`x = Mod[a^((p + 1)/4), p]`

but it overflows.

Now I know I can use the PowerMod function, but what should I do if the original code was 
`x= Mod[a*2^((p - 1)/4), p]`?

Comment: You should still use PowerMod[a,(p+1)/4,p] instead. The result is a number independent of the code that is used to compute it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, always use `PowerMod` to compute large powers. I don't see an issue with your second formula, just do

`Mod[a * PowerMod[2, (p-1)/4, p], p]`